# Table of Contents in memoir with section style

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am using the document class `memoir` and would like to have the "Content"-title of the `\tableofcontents` in the style of a section instead of a chapter. Is that possible?

To be precise, I would like to do the same for `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables` and `\listoftheorems` (from the `thmtools` package). But I guess the answer for `\tableofcontents` can simply be adjusted for these.

Here is an MWE that generates a table of contents with the chapter style heading.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{My}
    \section{Awesome}
    \section{Table}
    \chapter{Of}
    \section{Contents}
    \section{Is}
    \section{Here}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: I would like to have the title style of `\tableofcontents` or `\listoffigures` to be in the style of a section. But the appearance within the table of contents (i.e. the words "Content" or "List of Figures") should be normally as a chapter (without numbering). I hope this clarifies any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is just the appearence of the title of `\tableofcontents`, then you can redefine `\@tocmaketitle`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tocmaketitle{%
  \section*{\contentsname}
  \tocmark%
  \@afterheading}
\makeatother
```

Similar for `\listoffigures` (lof) etc. Remember `\listoftheorems` use `\listoffigures` internally.

Comment: Oh. I think we're solving different problems. Is the OP's question the style of the Contents title or the style (i.e., level) of the Contents entry in the actual TOC list...

Comment: @jon hmm, might be. Then it is even easier in `memoir`

Comment: I added an EDIT to my question to clarify that. @daleif's solution seems to do exactly what I want.

Comment: @daleif If this is very easy (short) in `memoir`, it might be nice to document how this is done, since people may land on this page looking for just that information.